How to change default Bluetooth device on Fedora Linux
I have a problem where for some reason or another the internal Bluetooth doesn't work on my custom built desktop. Hench, I've bought several external usb adapters to try and fix the problem. I launch Windows and I can get it to work perfectly (as I have a dual boot system), but on Linux I've looked at so many posts and asked for help and nothing's come of it. I have Fedora by the way.
The problem is my Bluetooth Headphones do connect (Bose Ultra Quiet Comfort) but they constantly are disconnecting if I move more than 3 feet away from the PC. I think it has something to do with Linux trying to use my internal bluetooth instead of the external one I am plugging in. How do I disable the internal one and just use the usb?
I have also tried looking at lsusb and I get this:
braxten509@fedora:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:a729 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:00b9 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Basilisk V3 X HyperSpeed
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3142:0001 FIFINE Microphones FIFINE K670 Microphone
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 320f:504b USB HID GMMK 2 Full Size 96%
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

I see the external USB I believe, but no sign of the internal Bluetooth. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Here are the USB devices I've tried:

https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C7HDJTXW?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C1ZDYFSZ?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

Here are also my kernel drivers listed via HardInfo2:

So I was able to solve the problem with these two commands:
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb

